# Already expanded Persistent Bottom Sheet won't be fully visible anymore if keyboard opens

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I'm using a `LinearLayout` with `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"` and an `TextInputLayout` in it.

If the bottom sheet is already expanded and then a keboard opens, the bottom sheet will not be pushed up fully, just the `TextInputLayout` is visible but not the rest.
Is there a way that the expanded bottom sheet will be fully visible above the keyboard when the keyboard opens?

Here you can see my issue: [bottom sheet not showing properly after keyboard opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftcWz.gif)